# Inject to custom ConstraintValidator in gwt

Tags: gwt, bean-validation

I am trying to write a custom ConstraintValidator for gwt and inject an implementation of an interface into it.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.

Turns out that you cannot inject a gin managed class into a generated class.

The way I solved it was using the info in the following link:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-web-toolkit/rN476RgdGAM

and had to write/extend the ValidatorGenerator from gwt.

Lttle bit of work

```
<generate-with
    class=".... CustomValidatorGenerator">
    <any>
        <when-type-assignable class="javax.validation.Validator" />
        <when-type-assignable
            class="com.google.gwt.validation.client.impl.GwtSpecificValidator" />
    </any>
</generate-with>
```